# Utilizar o GridControl do DvExpress

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando DevExpress, onde o usuário clica em uma linha no GridControl, quando isso acontece os dados dessa linha são colocados em algumas TextBox, a dificuldade tem sido em descobrir o nome do evento que devo utilizar toda vez que o usuário clicar em uma linha, e como busco essa informação do GridControl.

Comment: [Documentação dos eventos do GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGridGridControlClassEventsTopic).

Comment: Sim, mas na descrição daqueles eventos não está claro, e utilizando o link ainda não responde a segunda parte da pergunta, como busco os dados do GridControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto era utilizar os eventos do GridView, ao invés do GridControl. Então usei o evento FocusedRowChanged assim toda vez que o usuário clicar em outra opção do Grid será executado o código.

```
With dtbTabela.Rows.Item(GridView1.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex)
        txtCampo.Text = .Item("dtcCampo")
        txtCampo2.Text = .Item("dtcCampo2")

End With
```

Esse código pega o index da linha que o usuário está clicando e depois mostrando em duas TextBox o valor.

Answer (score 1):

Embora confusa a pergunta, creio que quer obter um valor de certo campo de datagrid e envia-lo para um textbox, o evento se chama row.selected, vou explicar melhor:

> Suponhamos que temos uma tabela chamada GridClientes e ela contem 2 colunas "id" e "nome", para enviar o valor de "id" para um textbox, deve-se usar o seguinte código:

```
idclient.Text = GridClientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

o valor da célula é contado a partir de 0, logo... se tenho 2 campos, são eles Cells[0] e Cells[1].

> Este código pode ser chamado dentro do evento de um botão:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        idClient.Text = GridClientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

> Quando uma celula da tabela for selecionada:

```
    private void GridClientes_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        idClient.Text = GridClientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

> Ou quando uma linha inteira da tabela for selecionada (precisa configurar este recurso):

```
    private void GridClientes_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        idClient.Text = GridClientes.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: No caso foi utilizado o GridControl do DevExpress, por isso algumas opções são diferentes, além disso o objetivo era que toda vez que o cliente clica-se em um registro do GridView aparece-se em um TextBox

Comment: Neste caso minha resposta é inútil, mas a lógica ainda é a mesma, você deve seguir o evento grid.rowselected